# SuperAgent -- Fetching only the headers

Tags: http, get, http-headers, superagent

I am using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) from Node.

For a simple request like this, how can I fetch/request only the headers of the page, not the full-content ?

`request.get('https://google.com')
   .then((res) => {console.log(res.headers);})
   .catch(err=> console.log(err.status));`

I tried to find in the documentation and Google but couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#-head-requests

Comment: @CBroe yes, you are right. That's what I needed. I had overlooked the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CBroe for pointing me to [the right direction](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#-head-requests).

**For the visitors from the future** ...

What you need is to replace `GET` request with `HEAD` request.
For example, in my case, it would be:

```js
const request = require('superagent');

request
  .head('https://google.com')
  .then((res) => {console.log(res.headers);})
  .catch(err=> console.log(err.status));
```